# How can I use the object's functions in pure JavaScript, without using jquery?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use functions from an object, but having no success.

```js
let ops = [
    {'*': (a, b) => a * b}, 
    {'/': (a, b) => a / b},
    {'+': (a, b) => a + b},
    {'-': (a, b) => a - b}
];

let res = [];
let current;

for (var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
   current = ops[i];
   res = current(4, 2);
   console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have an easier time if you had one object or one array, as opposed to an array of objects.

Comment: Use eval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: @nullptr.t That solves a different problem, which may not be desirable.

Comment: @nullptr.t no [avoid eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Comment: `current` is an object containing one property.  it's not a function itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without changing `ops`, you need to take the function out of the object by getting all values of the object and take the first one.

```js
 let ops = [
    {'*': (a, b) => a * b}, 
    {'/': (a, b) => a / b},
    {'+': (a, b) => a + b},
    {'-': (a, b) => a - b}
];

let res = [];
let current;

for (var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
   current = Object.values(ops[i])[0];
   res = current(4, 2);
   console.log(res);
}
```

A smarter approach is to use only the functions in an array.

```js
 let ops = [
        (a, b) => a * b, 
        (a, b) => a / b,
        (a, b) => a + b,
        (a, b) => a - b
    ];

let res = [];
let current;

for (var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
   current = ops[i];
   res = current(4, 2);
   console.log(res);
}
```